# How to create new tag element in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create new element in Angular.js

```
<link url="http://google.com">google</link>
```

that will be converted to `<a>` tag, How can I do this?

The code so far:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('link', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        template: '<a href="" ng-transclude></a>';
    }
});
```

but It render google after a link and I don't know how to get the url.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do here - can't you make it an `a` tag in the first place?

Comment: @sgroves I'm learning Angular.js

Comment: yes but i'm not sure why you're creating the element with a directive. why not just put it in the html where it belongs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it in the linking function. Your directive would look like this:

```
app.directive('link', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        template: '<a href="{{url}}" ng-transclude></a>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.url = attrs.url;
        }
    }
});
```

If you're ok with creating an isolated scope for your directive, you can also do this:

```
app.directive('link', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            url: '@'
        },
        template: '<a href="{{url}}" ng-transclude></a>'
    }
});
```

Then the url attribute will automatically get put into the scope of the directive.

Comment: Why the inner of a `<link>` is after of `<a>`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: When I use developer tool I got `<a href="http://google.com" ng-transclude="" url="http://google.com"></a>google` url was not removed and google is outside.

Comment: Odd, do you have a fiddle or plunker that demonstrates this?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what is going on there. It may be worth a new question. It seems to work fine when it's an attribute directive (See http://jsfiddle.net/5JQ66/).

Comment: I aks another question I I think I know the reason for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268090/text-inside-tag-outside-of-output-tag-in-anguar-js/18268228#18268228