# Text inside tag outside of output tag in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a link tag in HTML:

```
<link url="http://google.com">google</link>
```

and code that transform it to `<a>` tag:

```
app.directive('link', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            url: '@'
        },
        template: '<a href="{{url}}" ng-transclude></a>'
    }
});
```

But using this text Google is outside and URL is not removed (it copy if from link to a tag). If I use an attribute it works fine `<div link url="http://google.com">google</div>` What's wrong?

Here is
 [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CE6WN/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the reason for this, the `link` if html tag (that from head to include stylesheet) that is single self closing tag, and it seams that how parser parse it before Angular is executed.